# Return different number of entities

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have next function:

```
def foo():
    try:
        a = bar1()
        b = bar2()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        return
    return a, b
```

As you can see there could be returned different number of values.
According to that further I should carefully check it:

```
if foo():
    x, y = foo()
```

But seems there is some overhead.
Is such approach good? Any alternatives?

Should I return `None` for both variables in except block to prevent double executing?

Comment: I would keep return consistent. If your method is expected to *always* return two values, and you are catching an exception and still expecting to return *something*, then I would agree with returning `None, None`.

Comment: Or `x=foo(); if x: a,b=x`

Answer (score 2):

This beats the purpose of `Exception`. Try to follow these guidelines:

1. If there's an exception, unless you know *exactly how* to handle it,
   don't catch it
2. You can subclass `Exception` for scenario-specific exceptions
3. Never use catch-all blocks like the one you have
4. Keep the return values from methods consistent

Consider this:

```
class SpecificException(Exception):
    pass


def foo():
    a = bar1()
    b = bar2()
    return a, b

try:
    a, b = foo()
except SpecificException as e:
    logging.exception(e)
    handle(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to not catch the `Exception` itself, and let the exception be handled from the calling function. However, this is not always desired. So, I would return `None` from the except block, if an `Exception` is raised.

If you still want this to not happen, (ie. to solve your overhead problem), I'd suggest you to simply `pass` from the `except` block, and let the function return `None,None`.

Comment: "return None from the except block". That would cause inconsistencies that have to be handled from calling functions. Expectation is `a, b`. So it should stick to that rule set and return `None, None`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested to return None,None to solve the overhead problem @idjaw .